# Check a username list and if they already exist Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV with 100 Usernames i have to check now if they already exist. Whats the best way to do that?
And is there a possibility that if the Username "marmar" is already used the programm checks by its own if username "marmar1" or if that is used aswell "marmar2" is free?

Is it easier to read the Usernames through the csv or should i copy them into Powershell?
examples of Usernames:

marmar
langas
ianmow
lowbob
berret
lawpaw1

etc.

Open for ideas and tipps.$

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV file looks anything like

```
"UserName","OtherStuff"
"marmar","blah"
"langas2","blahblah"
"ianmow","blahblahblah"
"lowbob","blahblahblahblah"
"berret","blahblahblahblahblah"
"lawpaw1","blahblahblahblahblahblah"
```

You can do that with something like this:

```
$freeUserNames = Import-csv 'D:\UsersNamesToCheck.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    $name  = $_.UserName
    $dupes = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$name*'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    $index = 1
    # check if the username is already in use and if so, increase the index number and test again
    while ($dupes -contains $name) {
        $name = '{0}{1}' -f ($name -replace '\d+$'), $index++
    }
    $name
}

# output on screen
Write-Host "Unused usernames:`r`n"
$freeUserNames
```

Possible output:

> ```
> Unused usernames:
>
> marmar
> langas1
> ianmow1
> lowbob
> berret1
> lawpaw2
> ```